# Nested iteration using iterators cloned with "tee"

Tags: python, iterator

I noticed a straight behaviour when I loop over multiple iterators in Python

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> X,Y = tee(range(3))
>>> [(x,y) for x in X for y in Y]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)]
```

I expected it to behave identical as

```
>>> [(x,y) for x in range(3) for y in range(3)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

What am I missing? I thought `tee` as supposed to return independent iterators..

Comment: I think you need to [understand Generators in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)

Comment: to rectify your own code just change one line to `X, Y = map(tuple, tee(range(3)))`

Answer (score 1):

You *exhausted* the `Y` iterator, so `zip()` stopped iterating. Iterators cannot be used repeatedly, once you iterated to the end, *that is it*. You'd have to produce a *new* generator for each inner loop.

For your usecase, you'd actually use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) here, with a `repeat` parameter:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(range(3), repeat=2))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```